# Select Distinct only one column, when there are multiple columns

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, bounce-management

I have the following query in SFMC:

```sql
SELECT 
    b.SubscriberKey,
    b.BounceType,
    b.BounceCategory,
    b.EventDate,
    s.EmailAddress,
    b.JobID
FROM _bounce b
LEFT JOIN _Subscribers s ON b.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE b.EventDate > DATEADD(D, -91, GETDATE())
```

But this results in duplicated and I want to get data by unique email address.
Is there a way to use Select Distinct or any other query to get unique data by email address only?

Comment: You are looking for ROW_NUMBER / PARTITION BY, combined with "WHERE rownumber = 1;  see here, accepted answer, section B: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/362754/select-from-sent-dataview-duplicate-value-error-occuring/362768#362768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime deduplicating rows based on some criteria is a requirement, the [windowing functions](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/) are my go-to.  I'd suggest reading through the [myriad of the answers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bmarketing-cloud%5D%20%5Bquery%5D%20partition%20%20user%3A5202) on here if you need some additional examples.

Here's a shorthand version.

```sql
SELECT top 1 with ties
    b.SubscriberKey,
    b.BounceType,
    b.BounceCategory,
    b.EventDate,
    s.EmailAddress,
    b.JobID
FROM _bounce b
LEFT JOIN _Subscribers s ON b.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
order by row_number() over (partition by s.emailaddress order by b.eventDate desc) 
WHERE b.EventDate > DATEADD(D, -91, GETDATE())
```

The `row_number() over (partition by` will number rows from 1 to x for each unique combination of the proceeding fields, sorted by the `order by` clause.  The `top 1 with ties` gives you all the rows that where `row_number()` is 1.